# Normal subgroup of a characteristic subgroup

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, characteristic-subgroups

I came across the following question while reviewing for my qualifying exams:

> Prove or provide a counterexample:
>
> If $M$ is a normal subgroup of $N$, and $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, then $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Looking at our assumptions, it does not seem like we have enough information to deduce that $M$ is normal in $G$. However, coming up with a counterexample has proven difficult. I have tried letting $G = D_4$ and $N = \langle r\rangle$, but that did not prove fruitful. I also thought of using the quaternions, but all of its subgroups are normal, so that wouldn't be helpful here.

Any advice for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The permutations

$$\{(),(12)(34), (13)(24),(14)(23)\}\subset S_4$$

are a characteristic subgroup of $S_4$, isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

As $C_2\times C_2$ is abelian, any subgroup is normal.  However The subgroup generated by $(12)(34)$ is not normal in $S_4$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! As a follow up question, is there a quick way to prove that the permutations you have listed comprise a characteristic subgroup?

Comment: The only elements of order $2$ are the ones of the form $(**)(**)$ or $(**)$.  An automorphism cannot take an element of the first type to one of the second type, as $A_4$ is characteristic in $S_4$.

Comment: Or alternatively note that any automorphism of $S_4$ will map conjugacy classes to conjugacy classes, and the only conjugacy class of size $3$ is the one consisting of elements of the form $(**)(**)$.

Comment: Also note that the statement is true the other way round: Every characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is a normal subgroup.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Funny that you mention the other way around; I just finished with that proof!

Answer (score 1):

As some intuition, the socle is a subgroup worth considering. We restrict attention to finite groups. For a group $G$, the socle $\text{Soc}(G)$ is the subgroup generated by the minimal normal subgroups of $G$. As normal subgroups are closed under intersection, $\text{Soc}(G)$ is the direct product of the minimal normal subgroups. In particular, $\text{Soc}(G)$ is characteristic in $G$.

Now a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ is of the form $S^{k}$, where $S$ is a simple group. So if the minimal normal subgroups of $G$ are $N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m}$, where $N_{i} = S_{i}^{k_{i}}$, then we may write $\text{Soc}(G) = \prod_{i=1}^{m} \prod_{j=1}^{k_{i}} S_{i}.$ So each copy of $S_{i}$ is normal in $\text{Soc}(G)$.

Now if $k_{i} > 1$, $S_{i}$ is not normal in $G$. The way we see this is as follows. Consider the conjugation action of $G$ on $\text{Soc}(G)$. This induces a permutation on the direct factors of $\text{Soc}(G)$. In particular, the orbits of this action are precisely the minimal normal subgroups of $G$. Effectively, $N_{i}$ is the normal closure of $S_{i}$. That is, $N_{i} = \langle gS_{i}g^{-1} : g \in G \rangle$. So the conjugation action of $G$ on a fixed copy of $S_{i}$ (which we call $S$) effectively moves $S$ around to each copy of $S_{i}$ in $\text{Orb}(S)$.

For an infinite family of counter-examples, take $G = A_{5}^{n} \rtimes S_{n}$, where $S_{n}$ acts by permuting the factors of $A_{5}$.

If we assume that $G$ has no Abelian normal subgroups, then $G$ has a very rigid structure and is determined by (i) the isomorphism class of $\text{Soc}(G)$, and (ii) the conjugation action on $\text{Soc}(G)$. Effectively, building on the (spirit of) the counterexample yields an efficient isomorphism test. See Babai, Codenotti, and Qiao ([https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/icalp12.pdf](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/papers/icalp12.pdf)) and its predecessor Babai, Codenotti, Grochow, and Qiao ([https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/soda11.pdf](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/papers/soda11.pdf)).

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! (+1)